# Is it true that Public keys with even y coordinate correspond to private key that are less than n/2 and vice versa? (Secp256k1)

Tags: wallet, private-key, public-key, ecdsa, secp256k1

The question is somewhat complex and directed to clearing thing out.

Suppose that `n` is the order of the cyclic group. It `n - 1` is the number of all private keys possible

```
n = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141
```

We also know that every private and public key has its modular inverse.
To get a modular inverse of a private key, we need to subtract the private key from `n`.

`n - privKey`

To get a modular inverse of a public key, we'll have to multiply its `y` coordinate by `-1` and modulo by the `p` - order of the finite field.

```
x,y = x, -y % p
```

A modular inversed public key has the same `x` coordinate as original public key, but different `y` coordinate, and the `y` coordinate is always different in its polarity.
If the original `y` was odd, in a modular inversed key it will be even, and vice versa.

If a compressed public key has `"02"` index at the biggining then it has even `y`. If it is `"03"` then it is odd.

The question is, if the `y` coordinate of a public key is even, does it mean that the corresponding private key is less than `n/2` by its value? If the `y` is odd, the private key is more than `n/2` ?

Is there any relationship between the eveness/oddness of the `y` (or `x`) coordinate and the value of the corresponding private key?

Is there any way to know that the private key is more or less than `n/2` while not knowing the private key itself?

Is there a way to find out the public key of an address that never sent Bitcoin but only received it?

Comment: It took me 2 tries to find a counter example to your claim: privatekey = 0d6a35eec96a4526450edf6cf0acbedcfec82133d6086efe5a1a8a0d9897d1e5 < N/2, compressedpub = 031ce10ff151c1f0ea39b8cdd49cce5d386a69a7d4af139feba4ea1086de71abc4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We also know that every private and public key has its modular inverse. To get a modular inverse of a private key, we need to subtract the private key from `n`.

Just a terminology note: that's a modular negation, not a modular inverse. The modular inverse of `v` mod `n` would be the number `a` such that `a*v = 1 mod n`. Modular inverses aren't relevant to your question I believe, just wanted to clarify this.

> A modular inversed public key has the same x coordinate as original public key, but different `y` coordinate, and the `y` coordinate is always different in its polarity. If the original `y` was odd, in a modular inversed key it will be even, and vice versa.

That's all correct. Negating the private key (in the finite field modulo `n`) corresponds to negating the point, and negating the point negates the Y coordinate, and given that the coordinate field size is odd, negation modulo it changes the parity.

> The question is, if the y coordinate of a public key is even, does it mean that the corresponding private key is less than `n/2` by its value? If the `y` is odd, the private key is more than `n/2` ?

No, there is no such relation.

> Is there any relationship between the eveness/oddness of the `y` (or `x`) coordinate and the value of the corresponding private key?

No, seeing the public key should not let you infer *anything* about the corresponding private key. If there was a way to learn anything, the ECDLP (elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem) assumption would be broken (that assumption roughly says that a computationally-bounded attacker who sees a public key cannot guess the private key meaningfully better than random).

> Is there any way to know that the private key is more or less than `n/2` while not knowing the private key itself?

No.

> Is there a way to find out the public key of an address that never sent Bitcoin but only received it?

That's an unrelated question, but in short: no. It does depend on the type of address you're talking about. For P2PKH, P2SH, or P2WPKH addresses clearly not, as a hash function is involved. For P2TR (taproot) addresses an X coordinate of a (tweaked) public key is encoded directly (unhashed), but without Y coordinate.

Comment: Thanks. Clears things out

Comment: I got a few more questions. Suppose that we have a Public Key that is generated by an "odd" private key like113*G.
What will happen if we try to "half" this public key using these methods?

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59972/half-of-any-bitcoin-crypto-public-key-public-key-half-is-possible

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4455904.0

Does "halving" an even Public Key makes any difference?

Comment: Then you obtain the public key corresponding to the private key (113/2 mod n)*G. Halving is just multiplying by (1/2 mod n) = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926418782139537452191302581570759080747169 (both the private and public key). Whether the resulting private key is odd or even depends on how many times that multiplication wraps around n.